# SHELL: Display oldest created files DATE and its path

Tags: bash, macos, shell

*macOS Majove*

I can find the oldest **Created** file in the directory:

```
cd /path/ && ls | xargs mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate | awk '{print $3, $4}' | sort -n | head -n1
```

Outputs:

```
2020-02-04 08:24:46
```

But I struggle to get its path displayed alongside. I would want something like:

```
2020-02-04 08:24:46 /Path/Filename
```

I can easily do it with `last access time` but not when it comes to creation time. Any help would be much appreciated. Pretty sure it is something simple, and I am just overthinking it :(

Comment: Could you please do post sample output of command `cd /path/ && ls | xargs mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate` in your question so that we could get better understanding on this one.

Comment: @Ryul : On MacOS, a simple `ls -tU -l` should already sort according to the creation time. If the bash-internal implementation of `ls` does not support this option, try to use an explicit path, such as `/usr/bin/ls -tU -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead of `xargs`. Then you can print the filename along with the metadata.

```
cd /path/ && ls | while read f; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' $(mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate "$f" | awk '{print $3, $4}') "$f"
done | sort -n | head -n1
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it outputs the filename: `2020-02-04 08:24:46 filename`. How would one modify it to output the fullpath to the Filename  e.g. `/path/filename/`.

Comment: Instead of cd'ing to the directory, use `ls /path/*`